# WordPress PHP version/info not being picked from cPanel PHP Version values

Tags: server

Within my WordPress dashboard, I am receiving the error that my PHP version needs to be  updated to v7.4 as it currently shows v5.6.40.

The thing is, I have actually gone into the cPanel for this website and updated the PHP version to 7.4, as well as some other option values.

From what I can see, it doesn't seem to be picking up any of these changes at all, from  WordPress as when looking at **Tools > Site Health > Info > Server**, none of the values line up with cPanel PHP version changes.

I am running WordPress 5.8.3 but would really appreciate your help as to where WordPress is picking up this info in Site Health as it's certainly not retrieving the info from cPanel.

Is there anyway of forcing WordPress to use v7.4 within `.htaccess` file?

FYI, I also have the following line at the bottom of my `.htaccess` file:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56___lsphp .php .php5 .phtml`

Do I need this line and could this be where this 5.6.40 version is being picked up from?

Comment: This is definitely the problem of the environment. WordPress uses what server offers.

Comment: You'd need to check the mod_php version in Apache (or the fastcgi configuration if you're using that). In general it will be configured for the server, not for each individual site on the server, so you'll need the central Apache configuration not just .htaccess.

Comment: Seems like commenting out the following line: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56___lsphp .php .php5 .phtml` within the `.htaccess` then read the server details, so all good.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like commenting out the following line:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56___lsphp .php .php5 .phtml`

within the `.htaccess` then read the server details, so all good.